# PHPUnit returns different results (for the same set of Zend Framework project files) on differnt location

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

My PHPUnit test environment is set to run against a ZF project. and all runs pretty well from one place. But when I move all project files (thru git clone) to another place, phpunit runs, but returns "OK (0 tests, 0 assertions)", While indeed there are couple of tests.

The same process worked well on 2 different locations, until I manually downgrade phpunit from 3.6.5 to 3.4.15 (which seems unavoidable for ZF projects). Not sure what's going wrong? OR if there is any execution log from phpunit I can check with?

my **phpunit.xml**

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./application/bootstrap.php" colors="true">
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="myTests">
        <directory>./</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">../application/</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory suffix=".phtml">../application/</directory>
                <file>../application/Bootstrap.php</file>
                <file>../application/controllers/ErrorController.php</file>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

</phpunit>
```

---

### **comes out:**

PHPUnit 3.4.15 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 9.50Mb

OK (0 tests, 0 assertions)

---

### **where expexted:**

PHPUnit 3.4.15 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.....

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 30.75Mb

### OK (5 tests, 11 assertions)

Answer (score 1):

You want to downgrade to 3.**5**.15 not 3.**4**.15 and just for good measure add `suffix="Test.php"` to your directory tag.

One of the two should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for the reply, edorian. I finally narrowed it down to the problem of having dot (.) in its directory path. Like:
/home/simon/git-clone will work fine;
/home/.simon/git-clone will not.

So the solution for me is easy, just to start the server on another location w/o dot in its path. I guess it's a known issue for phpunit 3.4.x. It's not happening on 3.6.3, though.

BTW, I tried to downgrade it to 3.5.15 from pear, but always got the latest ver. Here's the post about this:
http://dustyreagan.com/downgrade-phpunit-3-6-to-3-5-15/
But I'm not sure that is working fine with ZF. FYI.

Comment: @simonxy Nice link! That will definitely come in handy :) - If your problem is solved click the checkmark next to my answer to let people know they don't need to check this question again as it is solved. (Or write your own answer and accept that as the solution if you want to make what you found easier findable by others :) )